# kubeadm compatibility between "--cri-socket" flag and "init phase" argument

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubespray, cri-o

I'm trying to set which cri-o socket to use by kubeadm !

To achieve this I should use the flag `--cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock`

---

The current command is in the form `kubeadm init phase <phase_name>`. I must add the `--cri-socket` flag to it.

I edited the command this way `kubeadm init --cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock phase <phase_name>`.

Unfortunatly I am getting the **error** `Error: unknown flag: --cri-socket`.
=> It seems that the argument `phase <phase_name>` and the flag `--cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock` is not compatible.

How do I fix that ?
Thx

---

**##################Update 1######################**

**File** :  */etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml*

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.10.3.15
  bindPort: 6443
certificateKey: 9063a1ccc9c5e926e02f245c06b8xxxxxxxxxxx
nodeRegistration:
  name: p3kubemaster1
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
  criSocket: /var/run/crio/crio.sock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that may help:

1. Check `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` if it is properly configured.

> In addition to the flags used when starting the kubelet, the file also
>   contains dynamic parameters such as the cgroup driver and whether to
>   use a different CRI runtime socket (--cri-socket).

More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#workflow-when-using-kubeadm-init).

2. Check your init config file (`kubeadm init --config string` will show you the path do the configuration file) and try to add something like this:

---

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: "unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock"
```

---

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! Unfortunatly setting the flag in `kubeadm-flags.env` did not changed anything. And concerning `kubeadm init --config string`, I checked the content of the file and saw that the socket was already set (as shown in the **Edit 1** of my answer). It was two good ideas though... If you have anymore please don't hesitate ! thx

Comment: If you are interested in this issue and want more context you can check this post I made using your help provided above:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57868351/5512455

Comment: Thanks. I have post an answer to your second answer. Please take a look so we could possibly close both of your cases.

Comment: **In the end you were right !** The solution was to use the initConfiguration. In my tests it did not work because for some reason Kubespray was not using the initConfiguration that he itself generates (god knows why). So I forced him to use the config by modifying the kubesprays files themselves and adding the `--config` flag. 
Thx !