# Kubespray fails with "Found multiple CRI sockets, please use --cri-socket to select one"

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray, cilium, cri-o

## Problem encountered

When deploying a cluster with **Kubespray**, **CRI-O** and **Cilium** I get an error about having multiple CRI socket to choose from.

*Full error*

```
fatal: [p3kubemaster1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": " mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/external_kubeconfig &&  /usr/local/bin/kubeadm  init phase   kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir /etc/kubernetes/external_kubeconfig  --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/ssl --apiserver-advertise-address 10.10.3.15 --apiserver-bind-port 6443  >/dev/null && cat /etc/kubernetes/external_kubeconfig/admin.conf && rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/external_kubeconfig ", "delta": "0:00:00.028808", "end": "2019-09-02 13:01:11.472480", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-09-02 13:01:11.443672", "stderr": "Found multiple CRI sockets, please use --cri-socket to select one: /var/run/dockershim.sock, /var/run/crio/crio.sock", "stderr_lines": ["Found multiple CRI sockets, please use --cri-socket to select one: /var/run/dockershim.sock, /var/run/crio/crio.sock"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

*Interesting part*

```
kubeadm  init phase kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir /etc/kubernetes/external_kubeconfig [...] >/dev/null,"stderr": "Found multiple CRI sockets, please use --cri-socket to select one: /var/run/dockershim.sock, /var/run/crio/crio.sock"}
```

---

## What I've tried

- 1) I've tried to set the `--cri-socket` flag inside `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`:

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock --cri-socket=/var/run/crio/crio.sock"
```

=> Makes no difference

- 2) I've checked `/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml` but it already contains the following section :

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.10.3.15
  bindPort: 6443
certificateKey: 9063a1ccc9c5e926e02f245c06b8d9f2ff3xxxxxxxxxxxx
nodeRegistration:
  name: p3kubemaster1
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
  criSocket: /var/run/crio/crio.sock
```

=> Its already ending with the `criSocket` flag, so nothing to do...

- 3) Tried to edit the ansible script to add the `--cri-socket` to the existing command but it fails with `Unknow command --cri-socket`

Existing :

```
{% if kubeadm_version is version('v1.14.0', '>=') %}
    init phase`
```

Tried :

```
{% if kubeadm_version is version('v1.14.0', '>=') %}
    init phase --crio socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock`
```

---

## Theories

It seems that the problem comes from the command `kubeadm init phase` which is not compatible with the `--crio-socket` flag... (see point 3)

Even though the correct socket is set (see point 2) using the config file, the `kubeadm init phase` is not using it.

Any ideas would be apreciated ;-)
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it !

The initial kubespray command was:
`kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir {{ kube_config_dir }}/external_kubeconfig`

⚠️ It seems that the `--kubeconfig-dir` flag was not taking into account the number of crio sockets.

So I changed the line to:
`kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin  --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml`

---

*For people having similar issues:*

The InitConfig part that made it work on the master is the following:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.10.3.15
  bindPort: 6443
certificateKey: 9063a1ccc9c5e926e02f245c06b8d9f2ff3c1eb2dafe5fbe2595ab4ab2d3eb1a
nodeRegistration:
  name: p3kubemaster1
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
  criSocket: /var/run/crio/crio.sock
```

In kubespray you must update the file `roles/kubernetes/client/tasks/main.yml` arround line 57.

You'll have to comment the initial `--kubeconfig-dir` section and replace it with the path of the InitConfig file.

For me it was generated by kubespray in `/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml` on the kube master. Check that this file exists on you side and that it contains the **criSocket** key in the **nodeRegistration** section.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me for multiple cri sockets

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

Image pull command before initialization for multiple cri:

```
kubeadm config images pull --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

---

You can choose cri socket path from the following table. See original documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-runtime)

| Runtime | Path to Unix domain socket |
| --- | --- |
| containerd | `unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock` |
| CRI-O | `unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock` |
| Docker Engine (using cri-dockerd) | `unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock` |

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and came upon [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/4737) github thread.

Which than pointed me to another one [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1495).

This seems to be a `kubeadm` issue which was already fixed and so the solution is available in v1.15
Could you please upgrade to that version (I am not sure which one you are using basing on both of your question that I have worked on) and see if the problem still persists?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tracked which version of kubeadm was used by kubespray. Its **kubeadm-v1.15.3**. The last one it seems. :-/

Comment: I tried `kubeadm init` on the master and it failed as expected. Next I did `kubeadm init phase --cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock` and it worked. So the issue stated on github IS resolved. But in my case its `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin` which requires the `--cri-socket` flag. And this fails with the error `error: unknown flag: --cri-socket`

Comment: The issue is still to combine the `init phase` command with the `--cri-socket` flag...